# Ввод названия города - как лучше сделать

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.

Делаю мобильное приложение для диплома.
В нём есть поле для ввода названия города. Нужна проверка что бы город был реальным. Как лучше это выполнить? Прикрутить базу данных с городами (тут я поискал и пока не нашёл, может кто знает где есть) или может есть какой-нибудь способ это выполнить с проверкой онлайн или что-то вроде того?

Comment: Баз много, вот, к примеру одна в свободном доступе: http://gis-lab.info/qa/vmap0-settl-rus.html

Comment: С базой разумеется лучше. Это может быть необязательно полноценная таблица - можно просто внешним файлом подкрутить с наименованиями. Насчет где достать - можно поискать на гитхабе sql скрипты типа такого https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Legostaev/contry_region_city/master/script.sql. Но разумеется это не для слепого копирования.

Comment: Есть же кладр c api http://kladr-api.ru/integration

Comment: Ну и гугловое api есть https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=ru

Comment: Есть сервис [DaData](https://dadata.ru/api/suggest/#response-address) и у него есть функционал как проверок на существование, так и подсказки - т.е. вы можете при вводе пользователем адреса (в вашем случае только город) еще и показывать список подходящих городов. Взаимодействие осуществляется посредством обращения к REST API